# Using EchoLink with Satellite delivered Internet

Tags: echolink

I am new to Echolink and I have Hughes Net Satellite delivered Internet service. Can I use Echolink with my Satellite service since there is a longer delay involved. Thanks in advance for your response. Larry N4QDE.

Answer (score 3):

The EchoLink site talks about using satellite Internet, so you should be able to. You may experience a slight delay, but it will really only be noticeable for each party while awaiting a response. If you've ever seen live news coverage from a scene you will get the same effect.

> Anchor: "We're going to our reporter at the scene."
>
> Reporter at scene: *Abnormal 2-3 second pause* "Here we are at..."

As long as you're not stepping on each other, the signal will get there eventually.

Of note, you might have some firewall settings you need to adjust per the [EchoLink documentation](http://www.echolink.org/firewall-friendly.htm).

Comment: When I was working incoming phones, we used to get satellite-routed calls (from Alaska, for instance), and we've have this delay -- lightspeed for a 22,000 mile round trip to the comsat, twice (once from caller to me, again from me to caller).  It's still less than a half second, but it's noticeable.  Longer delays in news field reports are likely due to multi-hop Internet latency, which can add up to > 250 ms without the signal ever leaving the ground.